# Import user profiles in MOSS 2007 server into my SharePoint 2010

Tags: user-profile, migration

I want to import user profiles in MOSS 2007 server into my SharePoint 2010 server.

Can anyone please suggest how can i go about achieving the same.

Can we import user profiles using Business Data Connection in Configure Synchronization Connection in User Profile Service Application in SharePoint 2010.

Why i am doing this:

I want to crawl MOSS 2007 User Profile Database in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do this is backup your WSS3 farm and restore it to a temporary WSS3 farm (on 64-bit h/w etc.) without the content databases. Do an in-place upgrade to SP2010. The upgrade will migrate the SSPs to SSAs in the SP2010 farm. Back these up and restore to your production SP2010 farm, along with any configuration.

You can also restore your SSP database and restore that to your SP2010 farm. This requires some further configuration and Powershell work. See: [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx#SSP).